# Equivalent circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

It seems at first sight of the first circuit that all the resistors of resistance r are connected in parallel and i have thus simplified it to the second circuit. But then on numbering the nodes and redrawing the circuit i got the third circuit.
I got the same equivalent resistance for all the three circuits which i think is a coincidence because i do not not know why the second circuit is equivalent to the first one (i drew that way because the in the first circuit it seems that all the resistors are in parallel).
I basically have two questions:**Is the first circuit equivalent to the second circuit or the third circuit or both? Why is the second circuit equivalent to the first one if it is so?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they are all the same. 5 resistors R in parallel. The actual equivalent circuit would be the following...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fogOIP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Regarding "Why is the second circuit equivalent to the first one if it is so?":
All the nodes you marked as separate, are all connected by "wires", so they are all at same potential, and are indeed the same point (assuming the "wires" are ideal with no resistance, as it is in 99.99% of schematics).

Here's an example about this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frZ9Um.png)</sup>

All this means you can actually draw schematics in any way you want, you can draw wires 1 m long, you can draw them curved, in the shape of a dog, it doesn't matter.

Of course you should try to make your designs simple and easy to read, or it will be difficult for anyone to understand it.

Comment: I'm definitely going to add 'dog wires' to my schematics now...

Comment: @Sam it would certainly look like an interesting circuit

Answer (score 1):

They are all equivalent.

Assuming that the conductive wires (the thin lines on your schematics) have zero resistance, you can move a conductive crossing to anywhere on the conductors that share the same juntion. Nothing would change. You can shape, deform, slide those wires and crossings between each other and nothing would change.

As long as you don't:

- Cut a wire
- Hop over a resistor and tie it elsewhere
- Remove battery (or power supplies / current supplies)

> Is the first circuit equivalent to the second circuit or the third circuit or both? Why is the second circuit equivalent to the first one if it is so?

The battery wires and the resistor wires create a crossing. The "+" wire from the battery can move freely along all resistor wires. Same goes for the negative wire.

In your third picture,

You just split the terminals of the battery to the opposite sides. Then move the wire crossings of the resistors between each other. Same rules apply.

So, basically, if you can move a wire to another place in your schematics **without disconnecting it** from the network (*a.k.a sliding junctions*), then your circuit is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

All circuits are equivalent. In each circuit, you have 5 resistors with equal resistances in parallel in series with a voltage source.